# How can i focus on textfield in child file on click of an icon which is in parent file in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, refs, react-forwardref

What I am trying to achieve is focusing on TextInput present in child component when clicked on an icon present in parent file. I have tried using refs and forward refs but that means i have to wrap the component in forwardref which i am trying to avoid.

```
 const InputText = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
 <input ref={ref} {...props} />
  ));
```

My child file looks like this:

```
export const TextField = ({
    label,
    placeholder = "",
     id = "",
  isSecure = false,
   disabled = false,
   handleBlur,
   handleChange,
  value,
   ...props
   }: IProps): React.ReactElement => {
    const { labelStyle, fieldStyle, status=false, search=false,inputStyle, errorStyle } = 
        props;


   //some statements


  <View style={styles.elementsContainer}>
    <TextInput                                   //I want to focus on this
      .......
       .
       .
      onChangeText={handleChange(props.name)}
      onBlur={handleBlur(props.name)}
    />
</View>
);
};
export default TextField;
```

Below is my parent file where I have an icon and on click of it I trying this textfield to be focused.

```
return (
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setSubmitting(false);
  }}
>
  {(formikProps: FormikProps<{ searchText: string }>) => (
    <View style={status?styles.highlight:[styles.container,textFieldDimensions]}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={addressFocus}>             //This is the icon on click of it i am trying textfield child component to be focused.
         <Icon testID="home" name={IconNames.home} />         
     </TouchableOpacity>
     <View style={styles.textfieldContainer}>
    <TextField                                              //CHild component
      handleChange={formikProps.handleChange}
      status={status}
      handleBlur={() => searchFunction(formikProps.values.searchText)}
      value={formikProps.values.searchText}
      name="searchText"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      search={search}
      label="Search :"
      id="searchText"
      fieldStyle={[styles.field,fieldStyle]}
      inputStyle={styles.input}
      labelStyle={[styles.label, labelStyle]}
    />
    </View>
    </View>
  )}
</Formik>
```

);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after brainstorming i come to a simple approach which works for me as of now. But i am not crystal clear from ref part how its working.

so what i did is in parent file where i am passing props in child component like this:

```
   const toggle=()=>{
    setToggler(!toggler)                     This function changes state value which is boolean type from false to true and vice versa.
        }
<TouchableOpacity onPress={toggle}>           //toggle function called on onPress
         <Icon testID="home" name={IconNames.home} />
     </TouchableOpacity>
 <TextField
      toggler={toggler}                       //Now I am passing state toggler into child component, change of this state will re render the component
      handleChange={formikProps.handleChange}
      status={status}
      handleBlur={() => searchFunction(formikProps.values.searchText)}
      value={formikProps.values.searchText}
      name="searchText"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      search={search}
      label="Search :"
      id="searchText"
      fieldStyle={[styles.field,fieldStyle]}
      inputStyle={styles.input}
      labelStyle={[styles.label, labelStyle]}
    />
```

Now how i am handling refs in child component is that it focus on textinput on click of button.

**All this is happening in functional component, for simplicity react rules has not been taken into account only relevant pieces of code is shown**

```
 const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);
 const onClickFocus = () => {
     {props.toggler && inputRef.current?.focus();}  //If toggler changes to true then this function will execute and perform inputRef.current?.focus();
   }
  onClickFocus()  //Function is called here and later inputRef is utilized in textinput as ref={inputRef}
 <TextInput
      ref={inputRef}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      secureTextEntry={isSecure}
      style={search?  fieldStyle:[styles.inputBox, inputStyle]}
      editable={!disabled}
      value={value}
      {...field}
      onChangeText={handleChange(props.name)}
      onBlur={handleBlur(props.name)}
    />
```